Pod status shows OOMKilled but there is no sign of termination
I have a Kubernetes cronjob that spins up a pod every midnight. There is only 1 container inside. It fetches some data, does some calculations, uploads several files and exits (It is a python 3.10-slim container which is mainly doing git operations: fetches and pulls, which can be memory intensive). The container has resource limits defined, namely:
Limits:
    cpu:     300m
    memory:  2Gi
Requests:
    cpu:     300m
    memory:  1Gi

When I check the pods with kubectl get pods, I get the following:
NAME                             READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
my-scheduled-pod                 0/1     OOMKilled   0          11h

Looking into the pod with kubectl describe pod, it shows that the Status for the pod is "Succeeded", but for the container I see the following:
State:            Terminated
    Reason:       OOMKilled
    Exit Code:    0
    Started:      Thu, 08 Aug 2024 00:09:03 +0200
    Finished:     Thu, 08 Aug 2024 01:04:57 +0200
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  0

However, everything went according to how it should, the container did finish everything in about an hour and managed to upload the result files and exited successfully. There is no sign of anything which would indicate that it has been terminated, restarted or anything which would not be normal. I checked the pod/container logs with kubectl logs and was up and running during that time.
On the following graph, you can see the container_memory_usage_bytes with yellow, and the container_memory_cache with green:
Container memory usage over time
You can see that it is running with maxed out on memory usage for a while and at some point the the cache drops to 0 shortly after which it is increasing again.
I don't understand what went wrong here or why I the pod has been labeled as "OOMKilled" when looking at it with kubectl get pods as everything is normal from my perspective and the container has not been restarted nor terminated.

Is'nt it the case that the pod/container get's killed once your process finishes running? That would be normal behavior right?

This question is similar to: Kubernetes Pod vs. Container OOMKilled. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why would it make sense to keep the process running if it exceeds the defined memory limit? I thought that Kubernetes kills the process immediately when it detects memory usage above the specified limit for a container.
This question is not similar at all to the one you've linked. I am not trying to understand what get's OOMKilled, I am trying to understand why my container has not been Terminated even though it shows up as OOMKilled.

I see - thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure why your pod gets OOMKilled, so will leave the question open for others to answer.
